# If $A_t = cos(X_t)$ and $B_t = sin(X_t)$ find the infinitesimal increment for $Y_t = A_t^2 + B_t^2$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

If $X_t$ is Brownian motion, I'm not sure how to apply Ito's lemma to get $d Y_t$ for $ Y_t = A_t^2 + B_t^2$ where $A_t = cos(X_t)$ and $B_t = sin(X_t)$ in particular, I get confused because $sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1$ so shouldn't $d Y_t$ be just 0 and I'm not sure how to handle the correlation between $A_t$ and $B_t$ which are clearly not independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning using the trigonometric identity is correct and so applying Ito's lemma is unnecessary here. However it is possible and gives the same result.

In the case of $f(x) = x^2$, Ito's lemma tells you that
$$dA_t^2 = 2 A_t dA_t + d \langle A \rangle_t$$

This means we want to find an SDE satisfied by $A_t$. Ito's lemma applied with the function $\cos$ tells us that
$$dA_t = - \sin(X_t) dX_t - \frac{1}{2} \cos(X_t) dt$$
where we use the fact that $\langle X \rangle_t = t$. Using this, we also find that $d \langle A \rangle_t = \sin(X_t)^2 dt$.

Hence substituting into the first equation gives $$dA_t^2 = - 2 \cos(X_t) \sin(X_t) dX_t -  \cos(X_t)^2 dt + \sin(X_t)^2 dt$$

Similar calculations show that 
$$dB_t^2 = 2 \cos(X_t) \sin(X_t) dX_t -  \sin(X_t)^2 dt + \cos(X_t)^2 dt.$$
Hence,
$$dY_t = dA_t^2 + dB_t^2 = 0$$
as you predicted.

Comment: I am quite new to this whole topic, but wouldn't just using the trigonometric identity require some additional justification?

Comment: @MF14 Where do you think additional justification is needed? It is immediate once you've got what the objects involved are straight in your head, I think. If you can say what you think the difficulty will be then maybe I can write a comment talking that through which you might find helpful

Comment: what is $d \langle A \rangle_t$? I've never used the angle brackets.

Comment: @s5s $\langle A \rangle_t$ is the quadratic variation of $A$. You might also have used square brackets (i.e. $[A]_t$). In finance type texts, you also see notation something like $(dA_t)^2$ for the object $d\langle A \rangle_t$. If you know Ito's formula, I'd guess you must have seen one of these notations since it should be part of the statement.